# contentsCss classes show twice

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

When I specify a custom css using the contentsCss property of the config and then clicking the Styles drop down, the classes inside the custom css file show up twice. What am I doing wrong?

By looking in the Network tab of Chrome, when I load the page that contains the CKEditor instance, I notice the file is loaded once and initiated by ckeditor.js. But when I click the Styles dropdown, I see another request is made to the css file. I'm not sure if this is related to seeing the classes twice.

I've verified that the editor is being replaced once. Also the contents of the external css file truly have the classes defined once.

```
editor = CKEDITOR.replace("designerEditor", {
        extraPlugins: "widget,div,stylesheetparser",
        ignoreEmptyParagraph: false,
        autoParagraph: false,
        allowedContent: true,     
        stylesSet: [],
        contentsCss: "/css/style.css",       
        toolbar: [
            {
                name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools'], items: ['CmsDesignerSourceModeButton'] },
            { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'], items: ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo'] },
            { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection'], items: ['Find', 'Replace', '-', 'SelectAll'] },
            '/',
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'], items: ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'] },
            { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'], items: ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote', 'CreateDiv', '-', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language'] },
            { name: 'links', items: ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'] },
            { name: 'insert', items: ['Paragraph', 'Image', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'SpecialChar', 'PageBreak', 'Iframe'] },
            '/',
            { name: 'styles', items: ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize'] },
            { name: 'colors', items: ['TextColor', 'BGColor'] },
            { name: 'tools', items: ['Maximize', 'ShowBlocks'] }
        ],
        toolbarGroups: [
            { name: 'document', groups: ['mode', 'document', 'doctools'] },
            { name: 'clipboard', groups: ['clipboard', 'undo'] },
            { name: 'editing', groups: ['find', 'selection'] },
            '/',
            { name: 'basicstyles', groups: ['basicstyles', 'cleanup'] },
            { name: 'paragraph', groups: ['list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi'] },
            { name: 'links' },
            { name: 'insert' },
            '/',
            { name: 'styles' },
            { name: 'colors' },
            { name: 'tools' }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I had v 4.11.2 and I was using the "stylesheetparser" plugin instead of the "stylesheetparser-fixed" plugin. Using the "fixed" version supposedly fixes some caching issue.